# A question about an inequality

Tags: inequality

How to get the solution set of the inequality $$\left ( \frac{\pi}{2} \right )^{(x-1)^2}\leq \left ( \frac{2}{\pi} \right )^{x^2-5x-5}?$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint : take logarithms on both sides. This can be done since the logarithm is a monotone function.

then use the property: $\log a^b=b\log a$

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying either sides by $\left(\frac\pi2\right)^{(x^2-5x-5)}$

$$\left(\frac\pi2\right)^{(x-1)^2+(x^2-5x-5)}\le 1\iff \left(\frac\pi2\right)^{2x^2-7x-4}\le 1=\left(\frac\pi2\right)^0$$

$\implies 2x^2-7x-4\le0$ as $\pi>2\iff \frac\pi2>1,$

Now, if $(x-a)(x-b)\le0$ where $a\le b,$   $a\le x\le b$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\text{Since}\;\;0\neq a\implies a^{-1}=\frac1a\;,\;\;\text{ we get}:$$

$$\left(\frac\pi2\right)^{(x-1)^2}\le\left(\frac2\pi\right)^{x^2-5x-5}=\left(\frac\pi 2\right)^{-x^2+5x+5}\implies\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Denote $a=\frac{\pi}{2}$. then $\frac{2}{\pi}=\frac{1}{a}$

Recall $$\frac{1}{a^{\large{\text{expression}}}}=a^{-\large{\text{expression}}}$$

Comment: I made the power of $a$ a bit larger. :-)

Comment: @BabakS. - thanks :)